# Calculating neural network with arbitrary topology

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Reading about neural evolution in some `ppt` presentation I came across a phrase:

> network output is calculated the standard way

I successfully implemented a simple feedforward mechanism following some guides (using vector representation of weights - [1](http://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-backpropagation-algorithm-scratch-python/), [2](https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/), [3](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html)) and I understand (more or less) how recurrent networks could be calculated.

What I couldn't find is how would a neural network with arbitrary topology be calculated. Is there any 'standard way' (algorithm)?

I imagine one way (assuming feedforward topology), though very time consuming, would be to loop through all neurons until output is calculated.

I imagine another method could be organizing arbitrary topology into layers (also assuming feedforward topology - [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269514/how-to-identify-recurrent-connections-in-an-arbitrary-neural-network)) and then calculating it.

**QUESTIONS**

What is the 'standard way' to calculate arbitrary topology network output? / How to calculate arbitrary topology network output?

**ASSUMPTIONS**

1. A feedforward topology (recurrent topology as a bonus, probably much more complicated).
2. Bias node present.

PS. I'm working with `Python`, following NEAT paper.

Comment: Seems like a question more suited for CS StackExchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neural networks can't have truly arbitrary topology, there are certain restrictions:

- The topology must be (reducible to) a [*directed acyclic graph* (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). You might ask whether RNNs contradict this requirement: they don't, because every RNN can be [unrolled into a DAG](http://suriyadeepan.github.io/2017-01-07-unfolding-rnn/). There are [other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551389/cyclic-computational-graphs-with-tensorflow-or-theano), when cycles can be emulated in the network, but the way it's executed the network can be always presented as a DAG and the backpropagation is limited.
- The graph must have dedicated input and output nodes, such that no input can depend on the output. Input nodes typically provide the training data.
- There are also other restrictions, e.g. activation functions must be differentiable.

Now you can notice that these networks are very like feed-forward: the forward pass runs from the inputs to the outputs, the backward pass runs in the other direction. This is possible because a DAG can be [sorted topologically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). In fact, topological sort simply *is* the representation of a graph in a feed-forward manner.

As for cycle emulation, the number of iterations is always limited, because memory is limited. A network is effectively a DAG, with inputs, outputs and some repeated pattern in between, which can also be seen as feed-forward.

To summarize: the same mechanism that is used for simple neural networks is done for all networks (the *standard* if you like), but the network representation can sometimes look different.